# Setting NSView readonly-property tag on subclass

Tags: macos, nsview, readonly-attribute

I have a class derived from NSView. NSView has a declaration

```
@property (readonly) NSInteger tag;
```

How can I set tag property to some value in my subclass? I tried following in my header file

```
@property(readwrite, assign) NSInteger tag;
```

Then in implementation I have

```
@dynamic tag
...
- (void)setTag:(NSInteger)newTag
{
    _tag = newTag;
}
```

This does not compile, I get 'Use of undeclared identifier: '_tag'. How can I set tag to a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're hitting is that `_tag` doesn't exist in the context where you're trying to set it, but if you use `@synthesize` like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SOView : NSView

@property (readwrite) NSInteger tag;

@end


@implementation SOView

@synthesize tag = _tag;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.tag = 25;
}

@end
```

I tried this out in my own tiny test project and it worked perfectly fine.